# Why does Percival Everett change the relationship of Carolyn Bryant and J W Milam in The Trees?

Tags: character-analysis, historical-context, percival-everett, the-trees

The character Granny C in Percival Everett's *The Trees* represents an aged Carolyn Bryant, the woman whose dubious claim that [Emmett Till](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmett_Till) whistled at her led to his brutal murder. In real life, the men who carried out the lynching were Bryant's husband Roy and his half-brother J W Milam. In Everett's novel, however, J W Milam is *Carolyn*'s blood relative:

> Also at the gathering was Granny C's brother's youngest boy, Junior Junior. His father, J. W. Milam, was called Junior, and so his son was Junior Junior, never J. Junior, never Junior J., never J.J., but Junior Junior. The older, called Just Junior after the birth of his son, had died of "the cancer" as Granny C called it some ten years earlier. He passed away within a month of Roy, her husband and Wheat's daddy.
>
> <sub>Everett, Percival. *The Trees*. Minneapolis: Graywolf, 2021. p. 7.</sub>

In this telling, J W Milam is either Carolyn's brother or, since this brother is a "Junior," her father.

**What is the reason for this change?** Why is J W Milam portrayed not as Roy Bryant's half-brother, but as the father or brother of Carolyn herself? What fictional purpose does the change serve? Has Everett gone on record about the change? Have any reviewers, critics, or scholars of his work discussed this change and its workings within the novel?

Comment: change the relationship between A and B