# Why the short chapters in Percival Everett's The Trees?

Tags: percival-everett, the-trees

Here in all its glory is the entirety of Chapter 71 of Percival Everett's *The Trees*:

> Ho to Hind: "What the hell is going on?"
>
> <sub>Everett, Perceval. *The Trees*. Minneapolis: Graywolf, 2021. ch. 71, p. 213.</sub>

While this is the shortest chapter in the book, it is not much of an outlier. Chapters 15 (p. 44), 55 (p. 158), and 91 (p. 267) are also under a page each. There might be others of equal brevity.

The novel's 308 pages encompass 108 chapters, making the average chapter less than three pages long. The longest, Chapter 64, is ten pages (pp. 185–194), and consists almost entirely of a list of [names](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/26177/289). Its being the longest is thematically apt. But why are the other chapters so short? What is gained by breaking up the narrative into such compact chunks? It is not necessarily the case that these tiny chapters carry a lot of weight. If Chapter 71 had been left out altogether, for example, it would not have impeded the narrative at all. So, **what is the structural and thematic design behind keeping the chapters so brief**? What narratological purpose does this choice serve? Has Everett commented on this aspect of the novel? Have reviewers, critics, or scholars had anything to say on the subject?

Comment: This isn't new - Lewis Carroll did it in _Through the Looking-Glass_. Chapter X 'Shaking' consists of two paragraphs describing how Alice shakes the Red Queen (a talking chess piece in her dream) who starts to turn into a kitten, and Chapter XI 'Waking' consists only of the partial sentence _...and it really **was** a kitten after all._

Comment: @KateBunting that it’s not new does not preclude asking about why it’s used in this particular novel.