# Who goes to Graceland in The Trees? Ed Morgan or Jim Davis?

Tags: percival-everett, the-trees

At one point in Percival Everett's *The Trees*, Ed Morgan and Jim Davis find themselves in Memphis:

> "You ever been to [Graceland](https://www.graceland.com/)?" Jim asked.
>
> "No."
>
> "I was there once."
>
> <sub>Everett, Percival. *The Trees*. Minneapolis: Graywolf, 2021. ch. 83, p. 242.</sub>

Later, as Ed and Jim are on their way out of the city with their colleagues Herberta Hind and Helvetica Quip:

> Ed drove. He did not deliver them directly to the freeway that led out of Memphis. Instead he took a circuitous route through the rundown city. "Sorry about taking the long way," he said. "It's just that every time I'm in Memphis I have to drive by one place, not to get out, but just to pause and look."
>
> "Graceland?" Hind said and chuckled.
>
> "I've been there, but no," Ed said. "Here we are. [The Lorraine Motel](https://www.civilrightsmuseum.org/). There on the corner of that balcony. I was ten. That's why I'm a cop."
>
> <sub>*ibid.* ch. 86, p. 252.</sub>

**How to account for the discrepancy** that when Jim asks Ed whether the latter has ever been to Graceland, Ed says he has not, but then a day later he says to Herberta that he has been there?

- Did Ed lie to Jim out of embarrassment at having visited Graceland, then slip up and admit the truth later?
- Is Ed lying to Herberta because he does not want to admit that despite having visited Memphis several times, he has never seen Graceland?
- Is this merely an editing error, as with the misspelling "flare" for "flair" noted in a [previous question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/26177/289)?
- Or is this something else entirely?

**What might be the reason for this inconsistency?** Has Everett been asked about it? Have reviewers, critics, or scholars provided any explanation?